# Does removing a redundant superinterface from a Java class break binary compatibility?

Tags: java, binary-compatibility

In the following example:

```
interface I {
    int F = 1;
}
class A extends B implements I { ... }
class B implements I { ... }
```

the `implements I` on `class A` is redundant. If I remove it, does it break binary compatibility?

Background of the question: If I call `getFields()` on `class A`, I get the public field `F` from the `interface I`, but if I remove the redundant `implements I`, I no longer get field `F`.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Because I just tried this in jshell of Java 19, and without the redundant implements clause `A.class.getFields()` includes `F`. The only difference I could find is the result of `A.class.getInterfaces()`.

Comment: I tested the sample above now with Java 8 and 11. The results are confusing. I get all the fields from ```Interface I``` on both ```class A``` and ```class B``` with Java 11, but get an empty array for ```class B``` with Java 8. In my real world situation, I get the reverse result with Java 8 and 11 (empty array for the base class and fields from the interface on the superclass), both compiled with JDK compliance level set to 1.8.

Comment: I changed the order of processing the classes from A B to B A and get different results with Java 8. It looks like the behaviour depends on the order of the loadClass calls with Java 8?!

Answer (score 0):

Let's add a class C to the example. So you have

```
interface I {
    int F = 1;
}
class B implements I { ... }
class A extends B implements I { ... }
class C extends B { ... }
```

I rearranged them so the superclass is on top.

Since the superclass B implements I, and C is similar to B I'd expect that it also implements I. With that, the `implements I` on class A should be redundant and can be removed.

On the other hand, if you remove the `implements I` on class B, it would have impact on C which also would no longer implement I. So the `implements I` on B is not redundant, as it mandates that B and all subclasses do implement I.